# How to replace current timestamp in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Here is my SQL query, I am trying to replace the current timestamp to past date, for e.g. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to 16-03-2019 this date and see the output.

```
SELECT 
    p.ID, s.ID, p.SCREENCODE, p.SUBJECTCODE, s.SITECODE, 
    s.NAME, p.SUBJECT_PROTOCOL_NUMBER, 
    TO_CHAR(to_timestamp_tz(p.D_TOFMORETHAN3UBM_S, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
FROM 
    PATIENT p, SITE s
WHERE 
    p.SITE = s.ID AND
    (p.VPATIENTSTATUS_PATIENT_STATUS = 1 AND       
     p.V20149_SCRFAILUREACTIVATIONDAT IS NULL)
    AND p.DELETED IS NULL     
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(f.DPG1DP3)
          FROM F20034 F
          WHERE F.PATIENT = p.ID
            AND f.deleted IS NULL
            AND To_Date(f.DPG1DP3,'YYYY-MM-DD') = To_Date(SUBSTR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')) < 1)
ORDER BY 
    s.SITECODE, p.SUBJECTCODE, p.ID
```

Can someone help me on this please? as am very bad at dates :(

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag it. SQL is a special-purpose language and many vendors (Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, SQLite etc.) run with different dialects with specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use that date specifically, you can just replace it with a date literal. So:

```
 To_Date(SUBSTR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1,1,10), 'DD-MM-YY')
```

becomes:

```
date '2019-03-16'
```

Also, you should stop storing date/time values as character datatypes.